# Access JavaDStream data into mapWithState

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaDStream that contains some data. I want to access that data into a mapWithState function. Obviously, foreachRDD cannot be used because it runs only on the driver and collect() also cannot be used because it contains a lot of data. Any solutions?

Thank you!

Later edit:

```
JavaDStream<Pair<String, int[]>> filteredRates = rate.filter(f -> f != null);

Function3<Message, Optional<Integer>, State<MessageState>, Pair<Message, MessageState>> messageState = (
                    key, value, state) -> {
                if (state.exists()) {
                    // needs to access array from filteredRates rdds. 
                    return new ImmutablePair<>(Message, MessageState);
                } else {
                    //update state
                    return null;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Show us your code.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: You want to pass the values from `filteredRates` to `mapWithState`?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Pair<String, int[]> from filteredRates into mapWithState.

Comment: Your state expectes a `Message, Optional<Integer>`. What are those types? They don't seem related to your `filteredRates`.

Comment: They are not. The value(Optional) of mapWithState is irrelevant because I need to use JavaPairDStream for mapWithState and I put it as an Integer. The state will be a MessageState that will contain a Message decorated with the array from filteredRates if the key(Pair<String, int[]>) will match a string in the Message.